# jQuery get the total markup with the selected class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a markup like this.

```
<ul class="language-dropdown">
  <li class="lang-switch language_en "><a href="#"><img src="res/flags/en.png" alt="en"></a></li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_es "><a href="#"><img src="res/flags/es.png" alt="es"></a></li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_ja current_lang "><a href="#"><img src="res/flags/ja.png" alt="ja"></a></li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_de "><a href="#"><img src="res/flags/de.png" alt="de"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here you can see I have a class current_lang inside a li tag. Now I want to get the total html markup with the li who has a class named as current_lang.
So for that I made my jQuery like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var CurrentItem = jQuery('ul.language-dropdown').find('li.current_lang').contents();
 console.log(CurrentItem);
});
```

But this one is not getting the html markup. So can someone kindly tell me how to get the total markup [`<li class="lang-switch language_ja current_lang "><a href="#"><img src="res/flags/ja.png" alt="ja"></a></li>`]
with the matching class current_lang. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want outer html:

```
var CurrentItem = jQuery('ul.language-dropdown').find('li.current_lang').clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
console.log(CurrentItem);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3NHWm/)**

Answer (score 1):

This should give the html markup

```
$("li.current_lang")[0].outerHTML
```

OR

```
$("li.current_lang").prop('outerHTML')
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vefadaga/1/edit)